# Publish on users facebook wall

Tags: facebook

The users of the website I'm building should be able to publish a title, a picture and a link on their facebook wall.

I found many questions on the subject, but no decent answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to use the JavaScript SDK:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Load it up:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
}; 
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

Use the FB.ui method in your JavaScript file (fill in your data accordingly):

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
);
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but it looks like I'm missing something. The first part of the code you gave goes in the body of the page, the second part goes in the head, but I miss something to trigger the FB.ui function, right ?