# When I use Fb.ui to publish to a user's facebook wall, Firefox blocks hundreds of popups

Tags: facebook

I'm asking the user to publish something to their wall using FB.ui as described in the answer to [Publish on users facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644820/publish-on-users-facebook-wall). It works fine in Chrome, but when I try to use it in Firefox, it blocks the popup window. This would be fine, but facebook continuously tries to open up another popupwindow when it is denied, resulting in something like this:
[image: Firefox prevented this site from opening 359 pop-up windows]

How can I stop facebook from being so persistant?

Answer (score 0):

Is this on an external site implementing the Facebook JS SDK or a canvas app?  If it's the former, do you have 3rd part cookies disabled in FireFox?

Comment: It's an HMTML5 canvas game, but at the end, I use Facebook's FB.ui http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Comment: And I don't think cookies are disabled.

Comment: Can you confirm that 3rd party cookies are enabled?  Check: Settings > Privacy > Accept Cookies from Sites > Accept third-party-cookies